# how to make Dimple Scatterplot no aggregate

Tags: dimple.js

I am trying to build a scatterplot on Iris data using dimple.js.

Here is my Code:

```
<div id="chartContainer">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
  d3.csv("/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/iris.csv", function (data) {
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 500, 330)
    myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "sepal_length");
    myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "sepal_width");
    myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bubble);
    //myChart.addLegend(200, 10, 360, 20, "right");
    myChart.draw();
  });
</script></div>
```

Here is the result:
[image: Here is the result]

I know dimple gonna aggregate data based on `myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bubble);`, that's why there is only one bubble comes out. But I wanna every records of data have a bubble, how can I cancel aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you'd have a field in your data which identifies what the bubble  represents, which you could pass into the first parameter of addSeries as you mention.

```
myChart.addSeries("Observation", dimple.plot.bubble);
```

If you really don't have anything to distinguish what makes an element in your data distinct from another other than sepal width and length you can pass those in instead:

```
myChart.addSeries(["sepal_width", "sepal_length"], dimple.plot.bubble);
```

The last element in the array is used for colouring, so this will cause all bubbles with a different sepal length to be coloured the differently.  Therefore I would suggest adding a label for what the series represents after the two fields:

```
myChart.addSeries(["sepal_width", "sepal_length", "Sepals"], dimple.plot.bubble);
```

Comment: thanks, sorry for late response. This is the answer I need !